# How to set default image in fastapi without manually selecting image

Tags: python, fastapi

** How to set a default image, when a new bank will create using create_bank API, without using the upload profile API. How to set a default bank image.**

```
@router.post("/create_bank", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response_model=bank.AddBankOut)
def create_bank(bank: bank.AddBank, db: Session = Depends(get_db), current_user: int = Depends(oauth2.get_current_user)):
    new_bank = models.Bank(**bank.dict())
    db.add(new_bank)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_bank)
    return new_bank


@router.post("/upload/profile", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def create_upload_profile(file : UploadFile = File(...), current_user: int = Depends(oauth2.get_current_user)):
    FILEPATH = "./app/images/"
    filename = file.filename
    extension = filename.split(".")[1]

    if extension not in ["jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gif"]:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, detail="File type is not supported")
    token_name = secrets.token_hex(10)+"."+extension
    generated_name = FILEPATH + token_name
    file_content = await file.read()

    with open(generated_name, "w+b") as file:
        file.write(file_content)

    img = Image.open(generated_name)
    img = img.resize(size = (500,500))
    img.save(generated_name)
    file.close()

    return generated_name
```

Comment: what is the code without default image?

Comment: Usually you'll want to give a default image/URL back when the image isn't set in the DB, instead of storing a default image in the db - that way it's far easier to change later. You'll have to show the code where you're having trouble setting a default value.

Comment: I've added the create _bank and upload image API. How to set a default image without using the image upload API.